# Text allign how can i align text ignoring font Awesome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, text-align

How can i allign text so it will ignore the arrows ?
I want next line to start at the same point as first word.

I`ve used fonr awesome arrows and this is probably the issue as the browser treat this as normal txt.

Is there any way round this if I keep fontAwesome ?

[image: Picture to question above]

[image: Code right now]

[image: Working - this is how i want it to look]

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? If you remove the arrows form your screenshot, you have empty circles, so then what? What are you trying to align, and to what, and what markup are you using? What have you already tried?

Comment: I took arrow with a circle as one font from fontAwesome so it is one whole thing. I want text and just text to start at the same point ( align left) so on picture in second li I want word "components" to start in line with word "service" same with "device" and "interval" in 4th li

Comment: that is not a useful answer: please update your post after reading through the policy article on [asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask) because there aren't enough details in your post at the moment to understand what you actually want to do, and what you've already tried to do that, and where in that process you got stuck.

Comment: Not sure how else i can explain this. 

I took "coolapse" component from Bootstrap and add ul with some li in it also i added the fa-arrow-alt-cicrle-right from font awesome now when i add align-left if text is going to new line it is starting under the arrow not from the same margin as other words.

This is the issue only on small divices.

I added the code bellow the picture, maybe this will clarify more

Comment: Done it. 

I had to put text in a seperate div and display all li tags as flex